# idlk file gets created in MAC

Tags: macos, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I have a `program and a plugin` which makes me a indesign document via `indesign server`.
On running the program, it would make some API calls like `openDoc, CreateElement, closeDoc` etc and make the document ready.
Once the server opens the file on mac, it would create a `.idlk` file which would prevent the user from opening this document ( using indesign viewer).
As the Server instance which my program invokes isn't ended the  `.idlk` file is still present.

What i want to know is, whether there is any `API` to release the lock on document ?

As i see from this [link](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/plugin/solutions.pdf) the lock and unlock calls are pertaining to layers and guides, not for the document.

Answer (score 0):

closeDoc should release the lock.
To debug, check to see if the document is still open after executing the closeDoc. If it is still open you may need to specify additional parameters for closeDoc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem managing files in the book using ExtendScript (CS 5.5 on a mac). Closing the file would not release the lock and opening it again would crash the script. I ended up removing all stucked .idlk files through the script for the whole book.